# XamlReader.Parse exception

Tags: c#, xaml, parsing, underline

I have a problem with parsing a xaml string

```
(FlowDocument)(System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(string));
```

Got this exception

```
'Cannot create unknown type '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation}UnderLine'.' Line number '3' and line position '13'.
```

string looks like this

```
<FlowDocument xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"><Paragraph><Bold>text</Bold></Paragraph>
<Paragraph><Italic>text</Italic></Paragraph>
<Paragraph><UnderLine>text</UnderLine></Paragraph>
...
</FlowDocument>
```

Everything else except underline works. Anybody knows where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is `UnderLine` -> `Underline`.

Comment: Omg, impossible fault. Thank you very much.